# Label not showing up (Swift 4 SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift4

I am making a game in Xcode with Swift 4, SpriteKit. My crash detection is working, however when I try to make text appear onto the screen when the player crashes, the text doesn't appear. My game basically has the use control a rocket ship which must dodge meteors, the player also has the ability to fire bullets. I have detected when the rocket ship hits a meteor but cannot get text to appear onto the screen. I know for a fact that the crash detection is working, because whenever I add a print statement in the didBegin function, the print statement executes. So it must be that way im displaying the label, but im not sure what I'm doing wrong with the label.
Here's my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceship")
    let stars = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "stars")
    let meteor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "meteor")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        print(frame.size.width)
        print(frame.size.height)

        stars.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
        stars.zPosition = 1

        player.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:-320)
        player.zPosition = 4
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width / 2)
        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1



        self.addChild(player)
        self.addChild(stars)

        self.addMeteor()


    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        gameOver()

    }

    func addMeteor() {
        meteor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: meteor.size.width / 2)
        meteor.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        meteor.setScale(0.50)
        meteor.position = CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%300),y:Int(arc4random()%600))
        //meteor.position = CGPoint(x:0 , y:0)
        meteor.zPosition = 4

        meteor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        meteor.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        meteor.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2

        self.addChild(meteor)
    }

    func fireBullet() {
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.position = player.position
        bullet.setScale(0.5)
        bullet.zPosition = 3
        self.addChild(bullet)
        let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
        let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
        bullet.run(bulletSequence)


    }

    func gameOver() {
        print("Game Over!")
        var gameOverLabel: SKLabelNode!
        gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        gameOverLabel.text = "Game Over! You lost!"
        gameOverLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .right
        gameOverLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)
        self.addChild(gameOverLabel)
        print("Label added")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        fireBullet()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch:  AnyObject in touches {
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x
            player.position.x += amountDragged
        }

    }



    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        meteor.position.y -= 6
        if meteor.position.y < player.position.y - 300{
            meteor.removeFromParent()
            addMeteor()

        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? I call the gameOver() function in didBegin which is supposed to be executed every time collision is detected. But nothing happens? The meteor simply goes past the rocket ship. If someone could help me that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you are trying to center the label on the screen, you may try to add this to your code, on gameover func:

1.Try change the position to this

```
gameOverLabel.position = CGPoint(x: (self.scene!.frame.width / 2) - (self.scene!.frame.width * self.scene!.anchorPoint.x) / 2, y:(self.scene!.frame.height / 2) - (self.scene!.frame.height * self.scene!.anchorPoint.y))
```

2.I don't know if you have something that is over the label and affecting its view, so try to:

```
gameOverLabel.zPosition = 10 //A number higher than any other zPosition
```

3.The label may be too small...try:

```
gameOverLabel.fontSize = 30 //Adjust it to what you want
```

4.Just a tip:

move the:

```
var gameOverLabel: SKLabelNode!
```

to next line after the

```
let meteor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "meteor")
```

This way you will have a universal label, and do not have to regenerate the label every time.

If you do this, just a final tip...I don't know if you have a func like gameRestart() or something like this...but make sure that when you restart the game, you remove the label:

```
gameOverLabel.removeFromParent()
```

If you don't do this, when the app try to add the label again it will crash!

Hope it helps!

Comment: you need to work on your answer,  1) is bad advice,  never use the view frame size because the view and the scene may not be the same size, 2). never assume the anchor point is 0,0

Comment: Thank you! All I had to do was change the zPosition! Can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: This is the perfect answer, ignore @Knight0fDragon
Keep the good work up!

Comment: @PraneethEchuri hey look, something you never told us, a star field covering your entire scene with no transparency

Comment: @Knight0fDragon if you looked at the code you would have seen that. The whole point I provide the code is so that people can take a look at it.

Comment: did you provide your assets? no, how am I suppose to know what a star is

Comment: @Gabriel Rocco, I fixed your answer,  using `self.scene` even when on the scene class is ok, and it allows you to use the code on other types of `SKNode` as well. The reason why you want to use `scene.frame` is because when you get deeper into developing for SpriteKit, you will learn that it is best to design for 1 scene size and let the hardware scale, instead of having to design for an unknown amount of scene sizes.  You subtract your midway point by the size multiply by the anchor point to always know where your center is.  If my anchor was 1,1, then the center of the scene is -0.5,-0.5

Comment: Thank you @Knight0fDragon and sorry about this. Praneeth Echuri, i'm happy it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are not moving any of your objects as far as your physics in concerned.  You need to apply forces instead of manually moving a position.  Also your player dynamic is set to false, which means that he never moves, so contacts only happen on the meteor end.

Comment: So your saying that if I set the rocket ship to dynamic the label will appear?

Comment: From what I understand you are saying that crash detection for my player is not detected as the players rocket ship is set to static. Is this the reason why the label doesn’t appear?

Comment: No, I am saying you need to apply forces.  Right now the hand of god is moving your meteor, not the physics engine.  As far as the physics is concerned, the meteor is not moving

Comment: Okay, but how would that affect the label not appearing?

Comment: you answered that question yourself, why do you need me to answer it again for you?  `I call the gameOver() function in didBegin which is supposed to be executed every time collision is detected. But nothing happens? The meteor simply goes past the rocket ship`

Comment: I print something to the console in the didBegin function, and the print statement executes... The collision detection is working, even though I'm not moving the SkSpriteNodes the right way according to you...

Comment: When I wrote that I was referring to the label not printing. Everything else in the didBegin function works, its just the label

Comment: well that is not what you said.  Where is 0,0 located at, bottom left corner?  Your text is going to the left of that because of right align, which means negative space, or off screen.

Comment: 0,0 is located at the middle of the screen @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Then the gameover function is not getting called

Comment: I call it though?

Comment: Yup, that’s what happens when you are not concise with your questions.  Did you think of calling gameover on did move to see if the label prints

Comment: I am trying @Gabriel Roscos answer, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: In the future please provide better answers and comments... Not, "it should work"